# How To Partition An Old iMac?

Tags: partitioning

I have an old iMac (500GB HDD, 4GB Memory). How do I partition my disk to install and run (only) Ubuntu on it?

Another question, what are the differences between partitioning a disk as `/`, `/home`, and `/boot`, `/home`, `/usr`?

Should I partition my iMac as  `/`, `/home`, or `/boot`, `/home`?

How do I crate a "swapfile"?

According to my iMac's spec, how do I set the disk space for each partition?

I'm using the 19.10 Ubuntu.

Some say that the question is duplicate. But I cannot find the info I want at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you are using, some releases do not need a swap partition as they can use a swapfile (older releases require swap partition). Most beginners tend to prefer a single partition as it's easier to work with; but your backup strategy may find different partitions are useful (ie. your use case will decide; /home separate also makes switching to another GNU/Linux easier but re-installing Ubuntu is easy with or without it).  /usr usually is only used by server or specific software use cases.

Comment: I have never needed to use /boot or any other partitions except / and sometimes /home.  Using just / for the whole drive is okay.  A small EFI partition might be needed if not already on drive.  Can check with disks or gparted when using live USB/DVD.

Comment: Can you be more specific? E.g. 25GB for /, 475GB for /home.

Comment: Partitioning is not set in stone.  Most people recommend about 20 to maybe 40GB for /, but you can use the whole disk for root if you want.  Or you can use root and home partitions and use the rest of disk for home or just part of it.  As long as you do not have any important data that you must have, you can redo the whole thing if you don't like it.  You say an old iMac so do not trust hardware not to go wonky in time and lose data.

Comment: What about the swapfile? How do I setup the swapfile?