# Partitioning in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: partitioning, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10 is released. How do I partition my disk, and do I need the swap partition?

Comment: Let the installer do it. No swap partition is needed.

Comment: I would not recommend a swap partition. IMO a swapfile is better utilized than a swap partition. Please have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/1165477/968501

Comment: Two choices, about 25GB for /root and the rest for /home, or just one partition of /, but make sure it is big enough to hold everything(all of disk).  If new drive will need about 300MB for a EFI partition also.  It is better to go too big now than too small and have to expand after.

Comment: Use the 'something else' option on the installer.  It is the bottom choice.  I usually like to set up partitions with gparted before I install.  Can do it when you use 'try ubuntu' to make sure everything works.

Comment: The extra / partition usually helps save data if you need to reinstall or upgrade.  Not 100% so you should keep backups of important data.

Comment: Please take a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1177861/1001196

Comment: How do I setup a swapfile? If no swap partition is needed, then do I set the / partition as Primary or Logical? https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu on a single partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973252/installing-ubuntu-on-a-single-partition)

Comment: This question was not EoSS or EOL when it was submitted. I'm voting to Leave Open.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 19.10](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-19-10-release-feature/) only needs a swap partition if you use [Hibernation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate). If you do, the swap partition should be set to equal your memory size.

Otherwise, the [Ubiquity installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) used by Ubuntu will create an [optimally sized](https://opensource.com/article/18/9/swap-space-linux-systems) swap file. If later on you discover you need to enlarge the swap file, because of [very memory-hungry apps](https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-space/), it is far easier to enlarge a swap file than a swap partition.

Early on, before 17.10, swap partitions were also faster than swap files, but that was fixed two years ago. Now the only need for a swap partition is for Hibernation.

Comment: So if I use Hibernation, do I create both swap partition and swap file?

Comment: No. Hibernation? Swap partition = size of memory.